# xcode crashed while trying to run on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

since i updated my xcode to version 5.1.1 my builds / running on a simulator / device faild with a long problem report.

here is a small part of the bug report:

```
Process:         Xcode [569]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 520942841
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [171]
Responsible:     Xcode [569]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-05-20 17:53:11.050 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A497d)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  A73022B3-59C3-407B-C950-F4C9E0B2F9B4


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8bee87b640> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8bee87b640>
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): must provide a file handle or pipe
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8bee87b640> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8bee87b640>
  1: Sending performAction: to <DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell: 0x7f8bee87bc50> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8bee87b640>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff93d07024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010d136b10 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff93e6be15 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff93d06e2c +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff92a285c5 NOCOPY_SETTER_IMPL (in Foundation)
  5  0x000000010fd8ba7d -[DVTDeveloperModeHelper isDeveloperModeEnabled] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
  6  0x000000010fd8be72 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper shouldAskUserAboutDeveloperMode] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
  7  0x000000010fd8bedc -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper askToEnableDeveloperModeIfNecessaryWithCompletionHandler:] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
  8  0x000000010e2c149d -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
  9  0x000000010e2c20ed -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _runScheme:runDestination:invocationRecord:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x000000010e1f4420 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController runActiveRunContext:] (in IDEKit)
 11  0x000000010e343c69 -[IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton performRunAction:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x00007fff8b62e7ba -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 13  0x000000010d69af85 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 14  0x000000010d136842 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 15  0x000000010d568b0e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 16  0x000000010d6ebe09 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell performAction:] (in DVTKit)
 17  0x00007fff8b62e7ba -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 18  0x000000010d69af85 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 19  0x000000010d136842 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 20  0x000000010d568b0e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 21  0x000000010d633b0f -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in DVTKit)
 22  0x00007fff8b62bb96 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 23  0x000000010d64f9ef -[DVTMainStatusAwareButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 24  0x000000010d64f980 -[DVTRolloverTrackingButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 25  0x00007fff8b625261 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff8b61f888 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x000000010e0ed600 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 28  0x00007fff8b540949 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 29  0x00007fff8b4ea9e3 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff92c9560d start (in libdyld.dylib)
 31  0x0000000000000001
```

Does someone have an idea how to solve this bug? does it have to do with the code? or is it just a upgrade thing to xcode 5?
thanks!

Comment: Easy. Restart Xcode. Don't worry.

Comment: What is crashing? The title says Xcode is crashing. The question says that the builds are crashing. Please clarify the question.

Comment: While Building the app xcode crashed. and the error report is also from xcode

Answer (score 1):

Reset the simulator (Menu item `iOS Simulator` -> `Reset Content and Settings ...`).

Go to the XCode Product menu, hold down Alt and click `Clean Build Folder`.

Go to the XCode Organiser `Projects` tab and delete the derived data for the project.

Finally close and restart Xcode and the simulator.

If that doesn't work, try deleting the simulator data in your application support library - the folder `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`.

There are many ways that the XCode can get itself into an inconsistent state.  The above procedure should sort it out in most cases.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i done all steps but still the same error. any other idea?

Comment: There is Not such a dictory. More Ideas:-)?

Comment: It's hidden in the finder.  You'll have to use `Go To Folder ...` in finder, or open a terminal window and do `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support` then `rm -rf iPhone\ Simulator`

Comment: Ok, found it and could delete the content. But still Same error. Same error comes if i run the app on my Device. What can i do?

Comment: You could try deleting `~/Library/Developer`.  Make sure you have a backup first as this will delete all of your personal XCode settings.

Comment: Your final option is delete and re-install XCode.  If that doesn't work,  contact apple support - you get 2 free support incidents with your developer subscription.